# How much does the White House pay to their employees?

Tags: united-states, politics, economics

Once I [read](https://scontent.fsjk1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/26993953_1715369638513058_7172496884273502847_n.jpg?oh=cd53ba671dc7c9f3ed6ddad6e9caa374&oe=5B14809D) that White House has 377 employees and Brazil's Palácio do Planalto has 3.800 employees.

I wonder if this number, 377, is true and how much does the USA pay for White House's employees.

Comment: Note that there is a big difference between "employees" and "staff".  I'm sure that there are many more than 377 employees needed to keep the place clean and in repair.  The "White House staff" referred to in news reports would basically be people sitting at desks in the president's office.

Comment: This is going to be a pretty misleading number regardless, not all of the President's advisors are employed by White House Office (the Joint Chiefs of Staff, for example), and most members of White House Office probably aren't advisors.

Comment: (And, by extension, it's going to be hard to arrive at a common understanding of the terms "staff" and "employee" in the two very different government environments, so any comparison is going to be very crude.)

Answer (score 5):

According to [NPR](https://www.npr.org/2017/06/30/535069910/trump-white-house-staff-payroll-nearly-36-million-and-top-heavy) (which stands for National Public Radio, but this was on their website):

> There are currently 377 White House office staff in the Trump administration, about a hundred fewer than were on the Obama payroll in 2016. And, by way of comparison, coverage of Obama's 2009 report listed 487 staffers in his first year. Trump's total payroll adds up to $35,766,744. That's about $4 million less than Obama's was in 2016, his final year in office.

So at one point last year, there were exactly 377 office staff in the White House.  At that time, the total payroll was $35,766,744 or a bit under $100,000 per person.

It is not clear to me if this number is the equivalent of the Palácio do Planalto number.  This is reporting advisors to the president.  This may or may not be the same thing as the other number.  Also realize that the number fluctuates and may increase to as many as 500 paid $40 million without breaking precedent.

NPR is an independent entity, but it does receive some government funding.